# jQuery to submit and render template

Tags: python, jquery, flask, href

I sent a data to server using post in javascript. At the server it handles a data and return a html template. How can I open this template in new window

In app.py

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/test', methods=['POST','GET'])
def test():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        arg_name = request.form.get('post_data')
        return render_template('test.html', return_data=arg_name)
```

In index.html

```
<body>
<a href="send_data();" target="_blank">click</a>
</body>
<script>
function send_data() {
    $.post("/test", {post_data:"TEST DATA"});
}
</script>
```

In test.html

```
<script>
var res_data = '{{return_data}}';
</script>
```